# How can we really find where an object is at a particular instant of time?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, observers

We all know that to locate an object in space we use another object as a reference point. This location will not be the same for all observers. So different observers at different points will see the object at different distances.

So, what's the real location of the object in space? Suppose I remove all the matter from space except for one object and then try to find the location of that object.Then how will I be able to locate that object? What will be the reference point then?

Comment: Hello Kurosaki, and welcome to physics.SE! It is a bit unclear what you are asking, could you please clarify your question?

Comment: well hi Heather I've now simplified my theory a bit and its the best i could do Cause i am only 15 and just a small Physics Enthusiast

Comment: We use interactions with matter and mathematics to find relative positions between objects. As the answer by CountTo10  says there are no absolute positions. The main method is using lasers and the mathematics we have developed about light. Frequencies of light  do not change during the measurement and are reproducible in the lab.

Comment: But anna v when the light beam after hitting the object comes back to the Transmitter/receiver then we are finding the distance of the object from the receiver ,and the receiver itself is an object made of matter so it will also destroy with time..

Comment: @Kurosaki, I further edited it to make it clearer. I nominated it for reopening, as I think it now makes sense. Good luck with your question!

Answer (score 1):

We can't find the "real" location of anything , because the reference frames (or coordinate systems) that we use all are compared  relative to each other, but there no **one** place that everything  is measured from. In other words,  there is no fixed point in space to provide a "real" location.

If you read this link, it might make more sense.

[**A golf ball floating in space**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/274714/what-are-the-near-stationary-points-in-spaces-experience-of-time-relative-to-us)

Comment: i don't know what's the problem with the people on this site. Why am i not getting answers for this question..

Comment: **Everybody** that  uses this regularly  site has questions  that never got answers , I have about 20 / 30  unanswered questions myself.  If you are not happy, just resubmit it with any changes you think will improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: I have voted to reopen it , so best of luck with it.